# I can't install plasma. ERROR instaling appstream

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, plasma5, appstream

When I installed Arch linux, I installed GNOME 41 as a GUI.

But I want to install KDE plasma 5.

I run the following command as root:

```
pacman -S plasma plasma-wayland-session kde-applications
```

But executing this command freezes for a while installing the package `appstream-qt 0.14.6-1 x86_64` and then a bunch of errors appear!

I've copied down all the bugs everything looks important!

```
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.osbeck.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from archmirror.it : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.cyberbits.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from de.arch.mirror.kescher.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from phinau.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.f4st.host : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from archlinux.thaller.ws : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from arch.mirror.constant.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from archlinux.uk.mirror.allworldit.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.pseudoform.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from archlinux.mailtunnel.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.telepoint.bg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.chaoticum.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from europe.mirror.pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.cyberbits.asia :
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from america.mirror.pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from asia.mirror.pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: Failed to get file 'appstream-qt-0.14.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.lty.me : The requested URL returned error: 404
Attention: Failed to get some files
error: failed to commit transaction (failed to download some files)
There were some errors, so no packages were updated.
```

Help!

Comment: ? Enable the [extra] repo ? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/official_repositories#extra ......... Testing if a package is available, with a random mirror `wget https://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/linux/archlinux/extra/os/x86_64/appstream-qt-0.14.6-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst` → Minor version -2 is OK, not -1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.14.6-1 is no longer the most recent version of the `appstream-qt` package, so your package list is [out of date](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#Packages_cannot_be_retrieved_on_installation). The most recent one is 0.14.6-2. You need to first [update your system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#Upgrading_packages) with `pacman -Syu` and then run `pacman -S plasma plasma-wayland-session kde-applications` again.